# jquery dynamic stracture with Eq

Tags: jquery

i want to make a single submission with dynamic jquery script but it doesn't worked
what wrong with my code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#foo").each( function( i )
   {

        $("button#foo").eq(i).click(function()
            {
               var a = this.val();
               alert(a);
            });
   });

});

<div id="tabs-1"><input type="type" value="one"><button id="foo"></button></div>

<div id="tabs-2"><input type="type" value="two"><button id="foo"></button></div>

<div id="tabs-3"><input type="type" value="tree"><button id="foo"></button></div>
```

thanks mapet

Comment: Ids should be unique across all the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var a = this.value;
```

value is a property and not a method

In jQuery you can use

```
$(this).val()
```

Your whole code should be something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#foo").click(function(){
      var a = this.value; // or you can use $(this).val() 
      alert(a);
   });
});
```

***Edit***

Give all the button a class name and use class selector to assign click event. Change your button ids. ID should be unique in a document.

```
$("button.btnclass").click(function(){
    // to get the value of the input previous to the current button element
    var val = $(this).prev().val(); 
    alert ( val );
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ufaru)**

***Second Edit***

```
$(function(){
  $("button.btnclass").click(function(){
    var currentElem = $(this);
    var val = currentElem.prev().val();
    var id = currentElem.attr("id");

    switch(id)
    {
      case "foo1"  : alert("ajax1");
                    break;
      case "foo2"  : alert("ajax2");
                  break;
      case "foo3"  : alert("ajax3");
                  break;
    }
  });
});​
```

Comment: but rahul how i determine that click button.1 or 2? 

if(click button1)
{
  ajax get;
}else{
  ajax get 2;
}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are repeating IDs. IDs have to be unique. Also what you're doing doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have tab with the different content i want it to dynamic so that my code will not be redundant.. 

like.. 

$("#foo1").click( function()
   {
 content ... 1
       
   });

$("#foo2").click( function()
   {
 content ...2
       
   });

$("#foo3").click( function()
   {
 content ...2
       
   });